# C++, how do I find the address of a member function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function-pointers, member-pointers

I have a specific problem I'm trying to solve, I need to find the location (in memory) of a class's method.  I think I've hit a syntax constraint because a pointer to a method is handled as a `member pointer`  Example:

```
class Foo {
public:
  int targetFunction(int value) { return value + 5; }
};

DWORD findLocation() { // ignore the fact that DWORD might not equal pointer size.
  int (Foo::*address)(int) = &(Foo::targetFunction); // member function pointer
  void* typeHide = (void*)&address; // Remove type
  DWORD targetAddress = *(DWORD*)typeHide; // Convert type from void* to DWORD* and dereference to DWORD
  return targetAddress;
}
```

`int (Foo::*address)(int) =` **can also be written as** `auto address =`

Now, in VS2008, it says `Foo::targetFunction`'s address is "0x000F B890" but `&Foo::targetFunction` is "0x000F **1762**"

First, the member pointer works correctly using the member pointer operators `.*` and `->*`.  If I cast targetAddress back to a member pointer, it still works!

Second, the location **can** be a thunk function!

Finally, if I use VS2008's debugger to change the value of targetFunction from the `member pointer`'s address 1762 to the VS debugger reported value B890, my code works correctly!

**Is there a C++ specific way of getting the address value (B890) instead of the member pointer value (1762)?**

---

Upon request, here is code I'm trying to make work:

```
BYTE overwriteStorage[300][2];

void NOP(void)
{
  // hackish, but works for now.
}

void disableOlderVersions(DWORD _address, int index)
{
    //...
    _address = findLocation();

DWORD protectionStorage = 0;

VirtualProtect((void *)_address, 1+4, PAGE_WRITECOPY, &protectionStorage); // windows.h: Make Read/Write the location in code
{
    BYTE *edit = (BYTE*)_address;
    overwriteStorage[index][0] = *(edit+0); // store previous value to revert if needed
    *(edit+0) = 0XE9; // JUMP (32-bit)

    overwriteStorage[index][1] = *(edit+1); // store second value
    signed int correctOffset = (signed int)NOP - (signed int)_address - 5; // calculate 0xE9 relative jump
    *(signed int*)(edit+1) = correctOffset; // set jump target
}
VirtualProtect((void *)_address, 1+4, PAGE_EXECUTE, &protectionStorage);
}
```

if I replace the first line of `findLocation` from a `member pointer` to an actual `function pointer` it works perfectly.  However, I need to read&write to several class methods as well, this method is broken by the odd `member pointer`s.

Also, I've had some local functions not report the correct address either (recently).  Is there possibly another way to find function addresses without being constrained by the compiler behaviors?

Comment: `I think I've hit a syntax constraint` if you do that in c++ you know your doing something wrong

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem. What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @aaronman, To be frank, it seems like `member pointers` are "covering" the functionality I'm looking for instead of constraining them.

Comment: That's my point c++ has very few constraints and will pretty much allow you to do anything you want

Comment: @Johnsyweb, there is no other possible solution to my problem. Though considering, I have a plethora of dynamically linked code that is defined through interface classes.  I need the addresses of the functions so I can compare between different versions and types.

Comment: The fingerprint of `targetFunction` doesn't match the variable type you are storing it in, in the posted code.

Comment: @kfsone, ah my mind switched gears while writing that.  That works now

Comment: All of the posted code works. How are you trying to use the pointer? You're casting it back to the relevant type and using it? Or are you trying to use it *as* a [non-mber] function pointer? If that's the case, you cannot do this and have to create a proxy function, function object or functor to do the work for you.

Comment: I've seen C++ APIs versioned in a number of ways over the years but never like this!

Comment: @kfsone, Sorry!  I clarified the final line!  My problem is that `&Foo::targetFunction` is not the actual memory address but a member pointer.  I'm trying to get the actual memory address.

Comment: There's still some confusion here, then, which might be better clarified by showing the code that's not working. Are you (a) trying to get the location of the first by of the function that will be executed or (b) trying to get the address of a pointer to the member function? Please show the class declaration including the thing you are trying to get the pointer to, the thing holding the pointer and the code that tries to use it that is not working.

Comment: @kfsone, I added and successfully debugged the code by using `findLocation` with a *local function* and `disableOlderVersions`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to compress a **member-function** call into a single function pointer. It's not possible.

Remember:

```
Object x;
x.a(1);
```

is actually short for

```
a(&x /*this*/, 1 /*arg1, ... */); //approximation, leprechauns may be involved in actual implementations.
```

That first argument is crucial, it's going to become "this".

So you can't do something like this:

```
class Object {
public:
    void f(int);
}

typedef void (*FNPTR)(int);
Object a;
void (Object::* memberFuncPtr)(int);
void* nerfedPtr = (void*)memberFuncPtrl
FNPTR funcPtr = static_cast<FNPTR>(nerfedPtr);
funcPtr(1);
```

Because you've robbed the member function of it's object context.

There is no way to call an object member function without having both the address of the function and the address of the instance.

Comment: I understand.  There are already plenty of questions on SO that relate.  But in fact, I do not need to call the function pointer, so the instance address is useless to me.  Otherwise, +1 for good answer!